# PHP Recursive foreach loop

Tags: php, tree, foreach

I have a list of files in a directory in the format of YearMonthDay Time as below

```
20080508-120801suggestions.sql
20090508-120737categories.sql
20100508-120737articlelikes.sql
20110508-120737article.sql
20120508-120737comments.sql
20120508-120737loginusers.sql
20120508-120737popsearch.sql
20120508-120737suggestions.sql
20120508-120801article.sql
```

I want my PHP to display one item for the years then when you expand that it will then show you one item for the months then again one item for the day then in there all available backups for that day.

I have the first bit done where by it lists all the unique years and have been staring at the code for too long to know where to go next.

I am passing the variable year in to the URL so can pull that down as part of the code as required.

```
if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'sqlbackup/')) 
{
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        $isYearfound = 'false';
        //$dirlist = array();
        if (($entry != ".") AND ($entry != ".."))
        {
            foreach ($dirarray as $dirarrayyear)
            {
                if (substr($entry, 0, 4) == $dirarrayyear)
                {
                    $isYearfound = 'true';
                }
            }
            if ($isYearfound == 'false')
            {
                $dirarray[] = substr($entry, 0, 4);
                Print "<a href='myknowledge.php?mnpage=managedb&date=" . substr($entry, 0, 4) . "'>" . substr($entry, 0, 4) . "</a><br/>";
            }
            //Print $entry . "<br/>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: The code above works fine. What I want to do now is put in a recursive loop but it's beyond my capabilities.

The code above displays:
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012

I now want to show
2008
2009
2010
2011
 Jan
 Feb
 Mar
2012

Comment: Do you mean 2008 Jan , 2009 Feb , 2010 December etc .. something like that

Comment: You're not doing recursion there. There's no function which calls itself directly (or indirectly).

Comment: First of all the page will display a list of all the years as it currently does 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012. Then if someone clicks on 2011 it will expand to show available months if a backup for that month exists. So it could show 2008 2009 2010 2011 Jan Apr May 2012. And it gets this information from the file name $entry, 0, 4 shows me the year then $entry, 4, 2 will show me the months.

Comment: The code `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'sqlbackup/'` implies that you're storing SQL backups in a publicly accessible web directory ... are you *sure* this is something you want to do?

Comment: not permanently, this is still on my development server, it's location will be above the html root eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to Baba for all the help. This is the code I used in the end to resolve the issue.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'sqlbackup/');
$list = array();
foreach($dir as $file)
{
    if($file->isDot())
    continue;

    list($prifix,$surfix) = explode("-", $file->getFilename(),2);
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $prifix);
    $year = $date->format("Y");
    $month = $date->format("m");
    $day = $date->format("d");

    if(!isset($list[$year]))
    {
        $list[$year] = array();
    }
    if(!in_array($day, $list[$year][$month][$day]))
    {
        $list[$year][$month][$day] = $day;
    }
}
echo "<pre>" ;

foreach (array_keys($list) as $value)
{
    Print "<a href='myknowledge.php?mnpage=managedb&date=" . $value . "'>" . $value . "</a><br/>";
    if ($value == substr($_GET['date'], 0, 4))
    {
            foreach (array_keys($list[$value]) as $value2)
            {
            Print "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='myknowledge.php?mnpage=managedb&date=" . $value . $value2 ."'>" . $value2 . "</a></br/>";
            }
    }
}                               
//print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first part looks fine. But you probably want to pass the year and month in the URL so that the code then compares the first 6 characters of the filename, and then for those URLs generated it would pass the full 8 characters.

```
first pass date=2008
second pass date=200805
third pass date=20080501
```

Comment: Yes correct. I can do that. But my problem exists in saying if 2011 is in my $_GET['date'] variable how do I list all the years as they appear now but then when it reaches 2011 to then list all the available unique months as well before carrying on with listing the available years.

Answer (score 0):

hello Form what i see all the month are `05` so you would not get disred result ... i change the dates in my demo and i got this

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('PATH_TO_SQL_DIR');
$list = array();
foreach($dir as $file)
{
    if($file->isDot())
        continue;

    list($prifix,$surfix) = explode("-", $file->getFilename(),2);
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd", $prifix);
    $year = $date->format("Y");
    $month = $date->format("M");

    if(!isset($list[$year]))
    {
        $list[$year] = array();
    }

    if(!in_array($month, $list[$year]))
    {
        $list[$year][] = $month;
    }
}

echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($list);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2008] => Array
        (
            [0] => May
            [1] => Dec
        )

    [2009] => Array
        (
            [0] => May
        )

    [2010] => Array
        (
            [0] => May
        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [0] => May
        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan
            [1] => Feb
            [2] => May
            [3] => Dec
        )

)
```

You can not use this to build any kind of links you want  ...

Comment: Good man baba, I was beginning to think I hadn't explained very well. I will take a fresh look at your code tomorrow morning much appreciated.

Comment: also I don't mind the months being displayed in numerical I just thought it would be easier to explain on the forum

Comment: You can change it to what every you want .. that is why i made it simple and flexible ... you don't recursion .. to achieve what you want

Comment: Yes Baba. Top man. I now have an array halfway to how i need it. I'm gonna need to figure out how to have another 'field' under each month for the available days but you have definitely sent me in the right direction.

Comment: I just added this to your code and it's going the right direction. I'll post my full code when it's complete.
if(!in_array($day, $list[$year][$month]))
         {
          $list[$year][$month][] = $day;
         }

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script for you that my help.
It is not recursive but I think it does what you want and you don't need to make recursive at all.
please change directory paths/script names, etc to yours and it will work for you.

```
$dir = scandir('myfiles');
$prevyear=0;
$prevmonth=0;
$prevday=0;

foreach ($dir as $file) {

if ($file!='.' && $file!='..') {

    if (isset($_GET["year"]) && isset($_GET["month"]) && isset($_GET["day"])) { //if all three is set show file

        if (preg_match('/^'.$_GET["year"].$_GET["month"].$_GET["day"].'/',$file,$match)) {
            echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
        }

    } else if (isset($_GET["year"]) && isset($_GET["month"])) { //if only year and month set show days
        if (preg_match('/^'.$_GET["year"].$_GET["month"].'/',$file,$match)) {
            $day = preg_replace(array('/^\d{6}/','/\-.*?$/'),'',$file);
            if ($day!=$prevday) {
                echo '<a href="script.php?year='.$_GET["year"].'&month='.$_GET["month"].'&day='.$day.'">' . $day . '</a><br />';
                $prevday=$day;
            }
        }   
    } else if (isset($_GET["year"])) { //if only year set show months
        if (preg_match('/^'.$_GET["year"].'/',$file,$match)) {
            $month = preg_replace(array('/^\d{4}/','/\d{2}\-.*?$/'),'',$file);
            if ($month!=$prevmonth) {
                echo '<a href="script.php?year='.$_GET["year"].'&month='.$month.'">' . $month . '</a><br />';
                $prevmonth=$month;
            }
        }   
    } else { //if nothing set show years
        $year = preg_replace('/\d{4}\-.*?$/','',$file);
        if ($year!=$prevyear) {
            echo '<a href="script.php?year='.$year.'">' . $year . '</a><br />';
            $prevyear=$year;
        }
    }
}
```

}